# LINQ method to create objects of different types

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code inside a method:

```
var addresses = new List<MutateAddressData>();

var yearsDB = (from tr in this.uow.TaxReturns
                where taxReturnIds.Contains(tr.Id)
                select new { Year = tr.TaxYear, TaxReturnTypeId = tr.TaxReturnType.Id }).ToList();

var ibAndVpb = yearsDB.Where(y => y.TaxReturnTypeId == (decimal)TaxReturnType.IB ||
                                  y.TaxReturnTypeId == (decimal)TaxReturnType.VpB);
if (ibAndVpb.Any())
{
    var address = new MutateAddressData
                    {
                    AddressType = AddressType.TaxReturn,
                    CityId = customer.PaCity.Id,
                    CountryId = customer.PaCity.Country.Id,
                    HouseNumber = customer.PaHouseNumber,
                    HouseNumberPostfix = customer.PaHouseNumberPostfix,
                    Street = customer.PaStreet,
                    ZipCode = customer.PaZipCode,
                    Years = string.Join(", ", ibAndVpb.Select(t => t.Year.ToString())),
                    TaxReturnType = (TaxReturnType)ibAndVpb.First().TaxReturnTypeId,
                    };

    addresses.Add(address);
}

var averaging = yearsDB.Except(ibAndVpb);
if (averaging.Any())
{
    var address = new MutateAddressData
                    {
                    AddressType = AddressType.TaxReturn,
                    CityId = customer.PaCity.Id,
                    CountryId = customer.PaCity.Country.Id,
                    HouseNumber = customer.PaHouseNumber,
                    HouseNumberPostfix = customer.PaHouseNumberPostfix,
                    Street = customer.PaStreet,
                    ZipCode = customer.PaZipCode,
                    Years = string.Join(", ", averaging.Select(t => t.Year.ToString())),
                    TaxReturnType = (TaxReturnType)averaging.First().TaxReturnTypeId,
                    };

    addresses.Add(address);
}

return addresses.ToArray();
```

I want to create max two different objects here. One object for types that er `Ib` or `Vpb` and the other object is for all other types.

My senses tell me that I can achieve the same more easily, but I can't figure out how. What do you think?

Comment: Can you explain the intent behind `averaging.First()`? Why the first and not one of the others? Or are they all equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that most of the options of MutateAddressData seem to be identical for both cases, I'd extract that into a method. But then you'd need yearsDB to contain items of the type TaxReturn.

So you'd basically end up with something like this:

```
var yearsDB = this.uow.TaxReturns.Where(x => taxReturnIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();

var ibAndVpb = yearsDB.Where(x => (TaxReturnType)x.TaxReturnType.Id == TaxReturnType.IB ||
                                  (TaxReturnType)x.TaxReturnType.Id == TaxReturnType.VpB);
if (ibAndVpb.Any())
{
    addresses.Add(CreateMutateAddressData( customer,  ibAndVpb));
}

var averaging = yearsDB.Except(ibAndVpb);
if (averaging.Any())
{
    addresses.Add(CreateMutateAddressData( customer,  averaging));
}

return addresses.ToArray();
```

This is the method that's called:

```
private MutateAddressData CreateMutateAddressData(Customer customer, List<TaxReturn> taxReturns)
{
    return new MutateAddressData
                    {
                    AddressType = AddressType.TaxReturn,
                    CityId = customer.PaCity.Id,
                    CountryId = customer.PaCity.Country.Id,
                    HouseNumber = customer.PaHouseNumber,
                    HouseNumberPostfix = customer.PaHouseNumberPostfix,
                    Street = customer.PaStreet,
                    ZipCode = customer.PaZipCode,
                    Years = string.Join(", ", taxReturns.Select(t => t.Year.ToString())),
                    TaxReturnType = (TaxReturnType)taxReturns.First().TaxReturnType.Id,
                    };
}
```